# Dynamically remove field button not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code. I am able to add new field and appending the new field and  remove button. There is two problem.

1. Remove button is not appending properly. It should append just after the 
   strength every time.
2. It Should remove respected input fields salt field and Strength field of every column.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 100; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            var y = x - 1;
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="input-field col s6"><input class="salt" id="salt' + y + '" name="drugs[' + y + '][salt]" type="text" required><label for="salt' + y + '">Salt/Drugs</label></div><div class="input-field col s6"><input class="strength" id="strength' + y + '" name="drugs[' + y + '][strength]" type="text" required><label for="strength' + y + '">Strength</label></div>'+'</div>'+' <div class="s4"><a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="material-icons">remove_circle</i></a></div>');
           
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().remove();
        x--;
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row input_fields_wrap"> 
                                <div class="input-field col s4">
                                    <input class="salt" id="salt" name="drugs[0][salt]" type="text" required>
                                    <label for="salt">Salt/Drugs</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-field col s4">
                                    <input class="strength" id="strength" name="drugs[0][strength]" type="text" required>
                                    <label for="strength">Strength</label>
                                </div>
       
                                <div class="s4">
                                    <button class="btn btn-large light-blue add_field_button">Add more salt/drugs</button>
                                </div>
                                               
                            </div>
```

[I want it to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZEdw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link in the comment, it is better to restructure the *htmlString*.

You can try the following way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 100; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            var y = x - 1;
            $(wrapper).prepend('<div class="input-field col s6"><input placeholder="Salt/Drugs" class="salt" id="salt' + y + '" name="drugs[' + y + '][salt]" type="text" required><input placeholder="Strength" class="strength" id="strength' + y + '" name="drugs[' + y + '][strength]" type="text" required><a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="material-icons">remove_circle</i></a></div></div>');
           
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().remove();
        x--;
        
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row input_fields_wrap"> 
  <div class="input-field col s4">
      <input placeholder="Salt/Drugs" class="salt" id="salt" name="drugs[0][salt]" type="text" required>
      <input placeholder="Strength" class="strength" id="strength" name="drugs[0][strength]" type="text" required>
  </div>

  <div class="s4">
      <button class="btn btn-large light-blue add_field_button">Add more salt/drugs</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help but The remove button should be append in the same row and it should work something like this. https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Dynamically-Add-More-Form-Fields-czMore/  Please check this photo for reference

Comment: hey @mamun I want it to be like I have commented above. Please help.

Comment: @Ashutoshdwivedi, demo link suggest that it is better to restructure the html.....I have updated the answer.....plz check.

Comment: hey @mamun I am using Materializecss and still it is not working properly. It is working something like this https://ibb.co/RHhT1GS

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically generated elements do not respond when listening the event directly, you have to listen to the DOM on them like

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().remove();
        x--;
    })
```